# IIS 7.5 + MVC 5 + NInject + PostSharp - Suddenly 401 on remote machine

Tags: iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc-5, http-status-code-401

I have a web application developed in VS2013

- ASP.NET MVC 5
- NInject for IoC
- Sql Server 2008 R2 for a backing store (ADO, not Entity Framework, for DAL)
- IIS 7.5 (Not a web garden, max processes = 1)
- PostSharp 3.1.46.0

I have been developing and deploying on my local machine this application to a development server for months with not too many issues.

- App Pool is .Net 4.0 Integrated, using the ApplicationPoolIdentity
- Anonymous and Forms authentication are enabled.  Anonymous is set to use the App Pool identity
- File permissions are set for the application folder to give IIS AppPool\[mypool] read, list, execute access. (I tried full access, once, and it didn't help)

Last week, the development server reports a 401 (sc-status:401 sc-substatus:0 sc-win32-status:0) instead of showing me any forms from a remote connection.  Local connections, that is, when I access the app on the sandbox, or if I log on to the development server and access it locally, work as expected.  Any request from a remote machine fails.

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
>   You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

I tried recreating the app pool and re-assigning the app to it.  I tried aspnet_iisreg -ir.  I went through most of the "Similar Questions" to the right of this edit box, trying to find something close to my issue.  I erased the application from the server and redeployed to a new app, with new name and a new physical folder. KB2545850 hotfix didn't help.

My deployment strategy is an xcopy of everything but the web.config(s)  I maintain the web.config separately.  Please help diagnose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [ASP.NET MVC Deploying an app with forms authentication to IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140780/asp-net-mvc-deploying-an-app-with-forms-authentication-to-iis-7-5) it says:

> If you have a path leading to an eventual [Authorize] attribute, that will cause this - 
>   removing the RenderAction or allowing that action to render without [Authorize] fixes it.

That was similar to my issue.  I have a global filter to Authorize.  I recently added a partial view in a controller to display a serial number.  I added that partial to the _Layout, without the AllowAnonymous.  Since the login form used the layout, which used this partial, I couldn't log in until I logged in.

Adding an [AllowAnonymous] to the action resolved this issue.  I am thinking about how to more easily detect this for when it happens to me again.